# The way of sending patch request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The endpoint: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/current/** is for updating current logged in user.
needs these fields to update:
When I send data as JSON using POSTMAN to the endpoint:

```
{
    "first_name": "Amir",
    "last_name": "",
    "profile": {
        "location": "Florida",
        "profession": "Not being useless",
    }
}
```

How do I should send it in http package in flutter. currently I send this way below:

```
Future<void> updateCurrentUserInformation(Teacher newTeacher) async {
    const String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/users/current/";
    await http.patch(
      url,
      body: {
        "first_name": newTeacher.first_name,
        "profile": "" //HOW DO I SHOULD SEND A MAP TO UPDATE LOCATION AND PROFESSION?
      },
      headers: {"Authorization": "JWT $authToken"},
    ).then((value) {
      print(authToken);
      print(value.body);
    });
  }
```

How do I should send a map to update location and profession?

UPDATED:
even when I encode profile to JSON server returns : `{"profile":["This field is required."]}`

here is the code:

```
Future<void> updateCurrentUserInformation(Athlete newTeacher) async {
    const String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/users/current/";
    var profile = json.encode({
      "edu": newTeacher.education,
      "location": newTeacher.location,
      "profession": newTeacher.
      "image": "",
    });
    await http.patch(
      url,
      body: {
        "first_name": "amiramiramir",
        "profile": profile
      },
      headers: {"Authorization": "JWT $authToken"},
    ).then((value) {
      print(authToken);
      print(value.body);
    });
  }
```

Data on server side received:

```
<QueryDict: {'first_name': ['amiramiramir'], 'profile': ['{"edu":"something","location":"somelocation","profession":"being useless"}']}>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert your map into a JSON string. Use `json.encode(yourMap)`.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
Future<void> updateCurrentUserInformation(Teacher newTeacher) async {
    const String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/users/current/";
    await http.patch(
      url,
      body: {
        "first_name": newTeacher.first_name,
        "profile": json.encode(newTeacher.yourMap) //HOW DO I SHOULD SEND A MAP TO UPDATE LOCATION AND PROFESSION?
      },
      headers: {"Authorization": "JWT $authToken"},
    ).then((value) {
      print(authToken);
      print(value.body);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I've tried this. but server returns: {"profile":["This field is required."]} as you can see I've already defined profile.

Comment: @TheMir Check the code again, I forgot to encode JSON in "profile". Try now, it should work.

Comment: as I told you I already tried this way. Check the UPDATE section, please.

Comment: I think the dart side is fine and there could be a problem at the server-side, can you put some loggers on the server and check the body which is received at the server-side?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, DONE.

Comment: Your response on the server looks fine to me, but why is there no "image" property? The dart will send that in the body as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218709/discussion-between-zeeshan-hussain-and-the-mir).